# How to push object to array from for loop properly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make an array that including object by for loop but there is a problem, The shape what I want is below :

```
[ 
  { data: 'apple', label: 'Fruits'  },
  { data: 'banana', label: 'Fruits' },
  { data: 'mango', label: 'Fruits'  } 
]
```

So I tried to below way, but It's not working properly.

```
var arr = [];
obj = {};
var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'];
var label = 'Fruits';

for (var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++){
    obj['data'] = fruits[i];
    obj['label'] = label;
    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

The result is just same object pushed.

```
[
  { data: 'apple', label: 'Fruits' },
  { data: 'apple', label: 'Fruits' },
  { data: 'apple', label: 'Fruits' } 
]
```

Is this because of closer function ? How can I make it well?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's happening because the `obj` object is referencing to the same object and it is updated in each iteration.

**The same object `obj` is referenced inside the loop**

Move the object declaration inside the loop to create a new object in each iteration.

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var obj = {}; // <---- Move declaration inside loop

    obj['data'] = fruits[i];
    obj['label'] = label;
    arr.push(obj);
}
```

```js
var arr = [];
var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'];
var label = 'Fruits';

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['data'] = fruits[i];
    obj['label'] = label;
    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

---

A simple way to avoid this is using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array from old.

```
var arr = fruits.map(fruit => ({
    data: fruit,
    label: label
}));
```

```js
var arr = [],
    fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'],
    label = 'Fruits';

var arr = fruits.map(fruit => ({
    data: fruit,
    label: label
}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 8):

You are always overwriting the same object.

You need after the for line

```
obj = {};
```

for creating an empty object

```js
var arr = [],
    obj,
    fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'],
    label = 'Fruits',
    i;

for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    obj = {}; // <----- new Object

    obj['data'] = fruits[i];
    obj['label'] = label;
    arr.push(obj);
}
 
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A shorter way would be the use of [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr = [], 
    fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'],
    label = 'Fruits';

arr = fruits.map(function (a) {
    return { data: a, label: label };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: The first `obj = {}` is useless the, isn't it?

Comment: @isvforall, where, what?

Answer (score 6):

You should create new object `obj` inside the loop, you was always reference to the same object.

```
var arr = [];
var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango'];
var label = 'Fruits';

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj['data'] = fruits[i];
    obj['label'] = label;
    arr.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. This is because when you do following, you're only pushing a 'reference' to the object and when the object value is updated in the loop, the object that was pushed also changes value because it was merely a 'reference' and eventually the last value that was set in the loop is also set in the 'references', hence you see multiple values of the last object that was pushed.

```
arr.push(obj);
```

So, to tackle this issue you do the following:

```
arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); //see Note below
```

The other way to prevent references is by doing the following:

```
let obj = { a: 1 };
let copy = Object.assign({}, obj); // Object.assign(target, ...sources)

obj.a = 2;
console.log(copy); // { a: 1 }
console.log(obj); // { a: 2 }
```

Note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone