# How to make for loop on react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

I making a select option using react-select following this [Installation and usage](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) example code.

There was an object of array to store the option like this:

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];
```

Now, I want to make it dynamically to store the value from other data and make it iterate on the object.

like this:

```
const options = [
      { value: flavor, label: flavor },
    ];
```

The **flavor** on the value and the label are an array.
Let's say the array was store the data like this:

```
flavor = ['chocolate', 'strawberry', 'vanilla']
```

So, whenever the array added new value, the object of array above also add the value on the iterate.

So, how to making iterate in that..?

or should I thinking to figure out in the component..?

```
<Select
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={options}
/>
```

**EDIT**: the result what I want are the object inside the array is added according to the array values, let's say if we have one data inside array, then the `const options` store data like this:

```
const options = [
      { value: flavor, label: flavor },
    ];
```

then if the array store 2 data, then the `const options` be like this:

```
const options = [
      { value: flavor, label: flavor },
      { value: flavor, label: flavor },
    ];
```

The purpose of this are for make dropdown options on the select have dynamically values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figure out this with following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602215/8070090), this is the answer what I want base on my questions:

```
const options = [];
    obj = {}

    for(var i = 0; i < flavor.length; i++) {
      var obj = {};

      obj['value'] = flavor[i];
      obj['label'] = flavor[i];
      options.push(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use an `.map` function to dynamically created your options :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';


const options = [
    { value: 'flavor', label: 'flavor' },
    { value: 'yummy', label: 'yummy' },
    { value: 'red', label: 'red' },
    { value: 'green', label: 'green' },
    { value: 'yellow', label: 'yellow' },
];

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedOption: 'None',
    }

    handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: target.value,
        });
    }

    render = () => (
        <div>
            <span>{this.state.selectedOption}</span>
            <select
            value={this.state.selectedOption}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
            {options.map(({ value, label }, index) => <option value={value} >{label}</option>)}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-example

Comment: And to your question "or should I thinking to figure out in the component" the answer is yes. If you abstracted that into a component it would be scalable and easy to test.

Comment: I have figure out this, 
thanks for taking your time to answers my question :).

Comment: This answers implies the usage of the normal select component, but the question wanted a solution based upon the react-select library.