# When editing dropdown of form I've got this issue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to get value I inserted when creating the object in the form. In my case I've got a JSON called person which has a relation 1:1 with nationality. One person has one nationality in my case.

In the person form there's a dropdown called nationality that brings all nationalities from API rest.

This is how I can set the state of nationality and handleChangeInput method inside class Person.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    nationality: props.nation.name
  };
};


onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    nationality: e.target.value
  })
}
```

And Field where is my drop down:

```
<Field
   className="custom-select d-block w-100" name='nationality' }
   value={this.state.nationality} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
   component="select" placeholder={!input.value ? 'Please, insert a
                                   nationality' : input.value}>

   <option value="" disabled hidden style={{fontStyle:
                                   'arial',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Please , insert a nationality</option>

   { this.props.listNationalities.map(nationalities => {

   return(
   <option key={nationality._id} value={nationality._id} style={{fontStyle:
                               'arial',fontWeight:'bold'}}>{nationality.name}</option>
   )
   })}

</Field>
```

All I want is that nationality dropdown to have 4 nationalities in the following order: 1) chinese, 2) russian, 3) american, 4) german

When I'm creating the person, I insert russian as person's nationality. And when editing the person created opening correspondent form, should appear in nationality russian and not the first element from the dropdown that is "chinese".

Comment: what you can do is during component getting mounted make the list nationalities API call on componentDidMount and store it in the state. A possible solution for select in react -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642605/how-to-make-for-loop-on-react-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML code

```
{
  this.props.listNationalities.map(** nationalities ** => {
    return (
      <option
        key={nationality._id}
        value={nationality._id}
        style={{
          fontStyle:'arial',
          fontWeight:'bold'
        }}
      >
      {nationality.name}
      </option>
  )})
}
```

1. In map method instead of using 'nationalities' use 'nationality'
2. For issue 'while editing ....', check the case of the value you are saving.