# Array.push is correctly pushing iterated objects to an array, but once the array is returned by method, all object properties have become the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below code is a method for my constructor for the class Word which is part of a word-search app I am building.

```
createCoordinates () {
        let result = []
        let printDir = getPrintDirection(this)
        let startPos = this.startPos
        let coord = {x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y}
        for (let i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
            result.push (coord)
            coord.x = coord.x + printDir.x
            coord.y = coord.y + printDir.y
        }
        return result
    } 
  
}
```

When a new Word is created, the method needs to create an array of board coordinates that the word covers.

Firstly the method creates an empty array: result.

Then it obtains a printDir value (for example {x: 0, y: 1} that dictates how much to change coordinates by for each letter, depending on word direction.

Starting with the startPos value, which is already defined for the word object, it should push a value to the array for each letter in the word, and increment the values in coord according to the direction the word is moving in, and then finally return the array of objects which should reflect all the board squares the word is covering.

So a four letter word moving top to bottom starting at the position: {x: 1, y: 1} should return something like:

[{x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:3}, {x:1, y:4}]

From logging inside the loop I can see the coord variable is changing as required, however when I log the array 'result' all the values have become the a different new value which is the value for the letter/iteration after the word should finish. To use the above example the array would look like this:

[{x:1, y:5}, {x:1, y:5}, {x:1, y:5}, {x:1, y:5}]

If I log the progress of the array within the loop, in the 1st iteration I can see that this has already taken place.

I'm stumped by this problem so any help would be appreciated, and I can share all of my code if this would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)

Comment: Move `let coord = ...` into the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push object to array from for loop properly in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602160/how-to-push-object-to-array-from-for-loop-properly-in-javascript)

Comment: @ggorlen If I move let coord and set it to startPos it will on each run of the loop reset to the start Position and create an array of all the same objects, but this time all matching the start co-ordinates.

Comment: Try `result.push(...coord)` then to copy the object, or change your logic to get the coordinates you want, maybe by using a separate object to accumulate the `printDir`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your code:

You have an object `coord`. You are pushing its reference to the array, in each iteration. All your array elements point to `coord`. You are changing the properties of the object `coord` again in turn changing your array elements.

```
        let coord = {x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y}
        for (let i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
           
           result.push ({x : coord.x , y : coord.y})
            coord.x = coord.x + printDir.x
            coord.y = coord.y + printDir.y
        }
        return result
```

I am now sending a new object in each loop.

Comment: With the above code having the declaration inside the loop resets coord back to the startPos.x/y values. So I get an array of values that matches the start position value in that scenario.

Comment: I have edited the code. I am passing a new object each time.

Comment: Glad. Consider upvoting/accepting the answer in that case.